# is there a tornado-ish equation or vector 3D?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces, vectors

### the formula

I've successfully found that  $m = 2\ln(x^2+y^2) $ look like a really static and not moving tornado.

But in the same time with vector equation I've found how to twist a cylinder.

$ r = \sin(v+\pi*u) $

$f(x,y,z) = (r * \sin(\pi*u),r * \cos(\pi*u), v) $

---

### adding time to the vector

if we add $\tau$ to $r$ the cylinder start moving like this

[image]

---

### the goal

So my goal is to make $m$ rotate like a tornado-ish. maybe incorporating the vector to the equation is the way,  but as of now i'm hitting a wall.

in short, the goal is the make the cylinder and $m$ look like a tornado, so it can spine like a bit like a tornado.

Comment: A function of form $z = f(x, y, t)$ cannot describe a tornado with a twisty or (very) off-vertical condensation funnel like in the Wikipedia [image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dszpics1.jpg) associated with the [tornado article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tornado), because the function is essentially a height map; the vertical distance from the "cloud top" down to the visible edge of the funnel at that planar point $(x, y)$ at time $t$. So, the *"wall"* is real, it is a limitation on the form you chose.

Comment: It might be possible with an implicit surface, i.e. $f(x, y, z, t) = 0$, where $t$ is a time variable, and $f$ describes the shape of the funnel as a function of time. For wind direction and speed, you'd need a vector-valued function, $\vec{f}(x, y, z, t)$, where the vector length divided by time unit yields the wind speed in the direction pointed by the vector at that point. But do note that I'd expect such a function to be pretty complex, not really worth the effort needed to construct one that is "convincing" (close enough to real world cases).

Comment: I don't know anything about tornados and hurricanes and winds but... there shouldn't be a differential equation modelling such a phenomenon? And from the differential equation maybe you can get some solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know what you are after, neither do I know anything about tornado’s, but perhaps something like an unstable spiral might be easier to describe such a shape. To be specific, I used a system of the form
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
\dot{x}_1\\\dot{x}_2\\ \dot{x}_3 
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} a & b & 0\\ -b & a & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & c \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
{x}_1\\{x}_2\\ {x}_3 
\end{pmatrix},\quad b>a,a>0,c>0
\end{align}
to have a growing unstable spiral. In the image I used $a = 0.05,b = 2,c = 0.01$, with an added sine input on the first coordinate to create the distortion ($2*\sin(t/10)$).

[image]

Comment: can you explain bit more ? if i want to use this as a vector i need to select each row of the matrice for x, y and z ?

Comment: Well, the 'tornado' you see in the picture is the solution for the given set of differential equations under a small non-zero initial condition. Using your favorite programming language you can probably solve this system and get back a timeseries of points $(x,y,z)$, or as I called them $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$. There is a lot to play with.